Ubuntu 24.10 about 6x slower than 24.04 after upgrade
After Upgrading Ubuntu 24.04 to Ubuntu 24.10 I've got a noticeable 5x to 6x decrease in CPU speed.
Here are some stats:
Ubuntu 24.04: https://adalin.com/ehtw.info/performance_2404 :
Hardware support: SSE/FMA3

fadd cpu+sse2:  0.124329 ms
fadd sse2:  0.105789 ms - cpu x 1.18
fadd sse_vex:   0.087300 ms - cpu x 1.42
fadd avx:   0.049802 ms - cpu x 2.50
fadd fma3:  0.048878 ms - cpu x 2.54 *

fixed volume:
fmadd cpu+sse2: 0.127262 ms
fmadd sse2: 0.103540 ms - cpu x 1.23
fmadd sse_vex:  0.103121 ms - cpu x 1.23
fmadd avx:  0.103710 ms - cpu x 1.23
fmadd fma3: 0.059296 ms - cpu x 2.15 *

with a volume ramp:
fmadd cpu+sse2: 0.185896 ms
fmadd sse2: 0.131996 ms - cpu x 1.41
fmadd sse_vex:  0.128179 ms - cpu x 1.45
fmadd avx:  0.096714 ms - cpu x 1.92
fmadd fma3: 0.059005 ms - cpu x 3.15 *

== by buffer:
fmul cpu+sse2:  0.114161 ms
fmul sse2:  0.074127 ms - cpu x 1.54
fmul sse_vex:   0.077581 ms - cpu x 1.47
fmul avx:   0.037785 ms - cpu x 3.02 *

== by value:
fmul cpu+sse2:  0.103737 ms
fmul sse2:  0.073450 ms - cpu x 1.41
fmul sse_vex:   0.070425 ms - cpu x 1.47
fmul avx:   0.049957 ms - cpu x 2.08 *

atanf:      2.138073 ms
atan cpu+sse2:  0.302981 ms - atanf x 7.06
atan sse2:  0.291542 ms - atanf x 7.33
atan sse_vex:   0.293946 ms - atanf x 7.27
atan avx:   0.216365 ms - atanf x 9.88
atan fma3:  0.178389 ms - atanf x 11.99 *

rms cpu+sse2:   0.253920 ms
rms sse2:   0.125264 ms - cpu x 2.03
rms sse_vex:    0.124908 ms - cpu x 2.03
rms avx:    0.073662 ms - cpu x 3.45    | error rms: 0.00%  peak: 0.00%
rms fma3:   0.073166 ms - cpu x 3.47 *  | error rms: 0.00%  peak: 0.00%

== Resample:
cubic cpu+sse2: 1.581679 ms
cubic sse2: 1.567997 ms - cpu x 1.01
cubic sse_vex:  1.569794 ms - cpu x 1.01
cubic fma3: 1.287460 ms - cpu x 1.23 *  | max error < 0.01%

== EMA filter:
freq cpu+sse2:  2.629481 ms
freq sse2:  2.628207 ms - cpu x 1.00
freq sse_vex:   2.630093 ms - cpu x 1.00 *

== EMA allpass filter:
freq cpu+sse2:  0.004096 ms *

== Butterworth filter (12dB/oct):
freq cpu+sse2:  2.754040 ms
freq sse2:  2.184368 ms - cpu x 1.26    | max error <= 100.00%
freq sse_vex:   2.184435 ms - cpu x 1.26    | max error <= 100.00%
freq fma3:  2.049643 ms - cpu x 1.34 *  | max error <= 100.00%

== Bessel filter (12dB/oct):
freq cpu+sse2:  2.785348 ms   - Butterworth x 0.99
freq sse2:  2.174103 ms - cpu x 1.28    | max error <= 100.00%
freq sse_vex:   2.213499 ms - cpu x 1.26    | max error <= 100.00%
freq fma3:  2.165815 ms - cpu x 1.29 *  | max error <= 100.00%

== DC-shift:
DC cpu+sse2:    0.198994 ms
DC sse2:    0.185940 ms - cpu x 1.07
DC sse_vex: 0.160182 ms - cpu x 1.24
DC avx:     0.087023 ms - cpu x 2.29 *

== wavefold:
fold cpu+sse2:  0.540282 ms
fold sse2:  0.597819 ms - cpu x 0.90
fold sse_vex:   0.361958 ms - cpu x 1.49
fold sse4:  0.478958 ms - cpu x 1.13
fold avx:   0.184964 ms - cpu x 2.92 *

== waveform generation:
wave cpu+sse2:  39.183221 ms
wave sse2:  9.834073 ms - cpu x 3.98    | max error <= 0.03%
wave sse_vex:   9.604297 ms - cpu x 4.08    | max error <= 0.03%
wave avx:   5.511502 ms - cpu x 7.11    | max error < 0.01%
wave fma3:  5.617067 ms - cpu x 6.98 *  | max error < 0.01%

== noise generation:
noise cpu+sse2: 5.290014 ms
noise sse2: 5.285387 ms - cpu x 1.00
noise sse_vex:  5.208737 ms - cpu x 1.02
noise avx:  5.178208 ms - cpu x 1.02
noise fma3: 5.218246 ms - cpu x 1.01 *  | max error < 0.01%

convolution (uses fastest fmadd):  0.639002 ms

Ubuntu 24.10: https://adalin.com/ehtw.info/performance_2410 :
 Hardware support: SSE/FMA3

fadd cpu+sse2:  0.648705 ms  
fadd sse2:  0.511280 ms - cpu x 1.27  
fadd sse_vex:   0.484869 ms - cpu x 1.34  
fadd avx:   0.269313 ms - cpu x 2.41  
fadd fma3:  0.269767 ms - cpu x 2.40 *

fixed volume:
fmadd cpu+sse2: 0.699896 ms  
fmadd sse2: 0.584900 ms - cpu x 1.20  
fmadd sse_vex:  0.581554 ms - cpu x 1.20  
fmadd avx:  0.534690 ms - cpu x 1.31  
fmadd fma3: 0.377294 ms - cpu x 1.86 *

with a volume ramp:
fmadd cpu+sse2: 1.038369 ms  
fmadd sse2: 0.706885 ms - cpu x 1.47  
fmadd sse_vex:  0.714611 ms - cpu x 1.45  
fmadd avx:  0.543704 ms - cpu x 1.91  
fmadd fma3: 0.324583 ms - cpu x 3.20 *

== by buffer:
fmul cpu+sse2:  0.648651 ms  
fmul sse2:  0.407225 ms - cpu x 1.59  
fmul sse_vex:   0.413529 ms - cpu x 1.57  
fmul avx:   0.208148 ms - cpu x 3.12 *

== by value:
fmul cpu+sse2:  0.571694 ms  
fmul sse2:  0.409509 ms - cpu x 1.40  
fmul sse_vex:   0.387298 ms - cpu x 1.48  
fmul avx:   0.275728 ms - cpu x 2.07 *

atanf:      9.839307 ms
atan cpu+sse2:  1.678538 ms - atanf x 5.86  
atan sse2:  1.614154 ms - atanf x 6.10  
atan sse_vex:   1.622608 ms - atanf x 6.06  
atan avx:   1.188525 ms - atanf x 8.28  
atan fma3:  0.989839 ms - atanf x 9.94 *

rms cpu+sse2:   1.401676 ms  
rms sse2:   0.702970 ms - cpu x 1.99  
rms sse_vex:    0.686821 ms - cpu x 2.04  
rms avx:    0.426370 ms - cpu x 3.29    | error rms: 0.00%  peak: 0.00%
rms fma3:   0.413929 ms - cpu x 3.39 *  | error rms: 0.00%  peak: 0.00%

== Resample:
cubic cpu+sse2: 8.702304 ms  
cubic sse2: 8.674493 ms - cpu x 1.00  
cubic sse_vex:  8.680173 ms - cpu x 1.00  
cubic fma3: 7.116650 ms - cpu x 1.22 *  | max error < 0.01%

== EMA filter:
freq cpu+sse2:  14.646985 ms  
freq sse2:  14.575244 ms - cpu x 1.00  
freq sse_vex:   14.548009 ms - cpu x 1.01 *

== EMA allpass filter:
freq cpu+sse2:  0.022266 ms *

== Butterworth filter (12dB/oct):
freq cpu+sse2:  15.228885 ms  
freq sse2:  12.063835 ms - cpu x 1.26   | max error <= 100.00%
freq sse_vex:   12.108820 ms - cpu x 1.26   | max error <= 100.00%
freq fma3:  11.333450 ms - cpu x 1.34 * | max error <= 100.00%

== Bessel filter (12dB/oct):
freq cpu+sse2:  15.387145 ms   - Butterworth x 0.99
freq sse2:  11.781728 ms - cpu x 1.31   | max error <= 100.00%
freq sse_vex:   11.859688 ms - cpu x 1.30   | max error <= 100.00%
freq fma3:  11.687472 ms - cpu x 1.32 * | max error <= 100.00%

== DC-shift:
DC cpu+sse2:    1.143795 ms  
DC sse2:    1.035423 ms - cpu x 1.10  
DC sse_vex: 0.895138 ms - cpu x 1.28  
DC avx:     0.479560 ms - cpu x 2.39 *

== wavefold:
fold cpu+sse2:  2.988734 ms  
fold sse2:  3.323692 ms - cpu x 0.90  
fold sse_vex:   1.994692 ms - cpu x 1.50  
fold sse4:  2.648162 ms - cpu x 1.13  
fold avx:   1.021319 ms - cpu x 2.93 *

== waveform generation:
wave cpu+sse2:  217.033348 ms  
wave sse2:  55.208769 ms - cpu x 3.93   | max error <= 0.03%
wave sse_vex:   54.861447 ms - cpu x 3.96   | max error <= 0.03%
wave avx:   30.672367 ms - cpu x 7.08   | max error < 0.01%
wave fma3:  31.291142 ms - cpu x 6.94 * | max error < 0.01%

== noise generation:
noise cpu+sse2: 29.657254 ms  
noise sse2: 30.109788 ms - cpu x 0.98  
noise sse_vex:  28.919762 ms - cpu x 1.03  
noise avx:  28.979033 ms - cpu x 1.02  
noise fma3: 28.949598 ms - cpu x 1.02 * | max error < 0.01%

convolution (uses fastest fmadd):  3.593110 ms

These are basic operations on buffers like adding a fixed value or multiplying the contents by a value for x86_64 code, SSE2 code and AVX code.
The system is:
   CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K @ 4.00GHz
   RAM: 16GB
   swap: 20GB
   GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750
   NVIDIA driver version: 560.35.03

BTW, 24.04 is LTS, but 24.10 is not. I would advice you to stay with 24.04. In 24.10, does it help if you change the kernel using the mainline tool?

I find that a strange advice; if nobody upgrades to the intermediate releases then these type of bugs would not be found until after the next LTS is released.I'm now updating to the 6.12.3 kernel to see if that makes any difference (I dind't know about the mainline tool before). If that doesn't help I'll revert back to an older kernel to see if that fixes it.

I tried to install the latest stable kernel with mainline but it failed to compile on one module (it mentioned NVidia) but then I noticed that the kernel used by Ubuntu 24.04 was still present (6.8.0-49) and I booted that one with the same results: 5-6x slower than before. After that I tried to recompile my own code with the tests, but that didn't help either.

Okay, I now run kernel 6.11.11-061111-generic but it doesn't fix the problem. I'm starting to wonder if this has anything to do with a changed scheduler maybe?

Bugs are off topic here.

To be honest I'm not sure whether it's a but or some configuration problem. I've now done the same test after booting Ubuntu 24.04 from an USB stick and it is instantly as fast as before. I've also tested with mitigations tuned off in the kernel which didn't help. So now we know it's not mitigations. It's not new CPU microcode. Maybe NVidia/Wayland?

Okay, switching to nouveau didn't help either. Update: I now realize the Ubuntu version on the USB stick was actually 24.10... So when starting 24.10 from USB the system was faster than the system after the upgrade.

Okay, I've reinstalled Ubuntu 24.10 on the system and that fixed it. Actually it was long overdue anyhow.
